# It's a good practice to use col-xs-* everywhere?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a template and my code looks something like this. It looks how I want to looks, but I don't know if it's ok technical talking.. Need some tips:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5  padding-box-product-image margin-image-product">
        <div class="pic-box-product">
            <img class="img-upload img-responsive" src="srcimg.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-7 width-content-product">
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding-left">
            <h2 class="col-xs-7 no-margin no-padding line-height-product title-product">Ttesta</h2>
            <p class="col-xs-5 no-margin dots-product-page line-height-product ">&#9679; &#9679; &#9679;</p>
            <p class="col-xs-12 no-margin no-padding line-height-product subtitle-product">Xytzadwa </p>
            <p class="col-xs-12 no-margin no-padding line-height-product date-product">My test</p>
            <div class="col-xs-12 decoration decoration-margins-product-first"></div>
            <img class="col-xs-4 img-responsive" src="/images/icon.png" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion your question could be a little more specific. If it works we can assume that it is technically ok. Anyway it is pretty common practice that developers doesn't use col-xs-12 as block elements stack one on another by default (of course there still can be cases where you have to force 100% width on your element).

Answer (score 2):

It looks ok, except all of the `no-padding` will elimnate the normal Bootstrap gutter (space between columns). Also, the nested columns should be wrapped in another row. From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

The last `img` shouldn't have `col-xs-4`. Place it inside a column instead. In general the grid `col-*` is for block elements like the DIV html tag. It shouldn't be for other elements that have other styles (h2, p, etc..)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5 padding-box-product-image margin-image-product">
            <div class="pic-box-product">
                <img class="img-upload img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/900x500">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 width-content-product">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7"><h2 class="line-height-product title-product">Ttesta</h2></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5"><p class="dots-product-page line-height-product ">● ● ●</p></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><p class="line-height-product subtitle-product">Xytzadwa </p></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><p class="line-height-product date-product">My test</p></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 decoration decoration-margins-product-first"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/70"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/hOXVBXdb5B